# How to show one column values into row in SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have one column like from query `SELECT * FROM Score_TABLE` and it returns a result like this:

```
Score
-----
  78
 712
```

Now I have to display it with query like this:

```
Score   Score2
---------------
  78       712
```

Points is dynamic.

```
select 
    a.Score 
from 
    (select 
         a.Score 
     from
         (select 
              concat(sum(s.bat_run), '-', 
                     (select count(s.out_type) from status s 
                      where s.out_type = 'out' 
                        and s.match_id = 77)) Score 
          from 
              status s 
          where 
              s.match_id = 77 
          group by 
              s.toss) a 
     where 
         a.Score = Score) a 
where 
    a.Score = Score
```

Result:

```
Score    Score2
---------------
 12        42
```

Comment: How many rows do you expect to be returned by `SELECT * FROM Score_TABLE`?

Comment: Why are your queries so nested? They are a lot more complicated than `SELECT * FROM Score_TABLE`. Also, how does the exact same query give two different scores? Perhaps they aren't the same - the layout makes them very hard to read.

Comment: Also, which database are you using? `[MySQL]` and `[oracle]` are two different databases with different syntaxes, albeit owned by the same corporation. Please don't tag your question with multiple database labels just to attract more eyeballs to your question. You're simply wasting the time of people who post solution you can't use.

Comment: ... and the results are not compatible with the query( there are two columns(`score` and `score2`) returning in the results, but there's one column `score` returning from the query )

Comment: You shouldn't be using the same alias `a` multiple times ......

Answer (score 0):

this will do :

```
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(score)
   FROM status 
   GROUP BY score;
```

Comment: Result is Showing Like this after executing this query
[BLOB - 3 B]
[BLOB - 3 B]

Comment: [BLOB - 3 B] [BLOB - 3 B]  whats that??

Comment: Hi! While this may be a solution to the question, code only answers are generally discouraged on SO. Please take some time to edit your response with an explanation as to why this is a solution as it will help OP and future visitors of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your question properly but i think you need to "PIVOT"

this may help you
[Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: thats ok you need to pivot but you have to give in appropriate answer this should rather be a comment

Comment: new at stackoverflow and i tried to comment it first, but i don't have enough reputation.